# Woocommerce - override single add-to-cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to override the single add to cart template from Woocommerce, which is located under `/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`.

I have already tried copying it into `/CHILD-THEME/templates/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` without success.

When editing the file directly in the woocommerce template I can see the changes locally, but not from the child theme.

Also `add_theme_support( 'woocommerce')` is added to my functions.php

I am using elementor and jet-woo-builder, but I could yet not figure out if those are creating problems.

The reason why I want to edit the file is because I'd like to give the 'add-to-cart'-button some data-attributes from the product (e.g price), which I want to access later on in the ajax add-to-cart event.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`/CHILD-THEME/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` was the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce files should be in `woocommerce` folder in your theme folder

```
yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
```